# jqgrid columns order

Tags: jqgrid

I have jqgrid which read data from json service

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: 'jsonservice',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Street', 'City'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55, align: 'center', width: '25' }
    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 120 },
    { name: 'Street', index: 'Street', width: 90 },
    { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 50 },
    ]
});
```

the json service returns data like this

```
{"page":1,
"total":37,
"records":722,
"rows":
[
    {"id":1,"cell":[1, "Sample name 1","Sample Street 2","Sample City 3"]},
    {"id":2,"cell":[2, "Sample name 2","Sample Street 2","Sample City 3"]}
]
}
```

How to change order of displayed columns to e.g. Name, City, Street, Id without changing order in json data?

Comment: I tried but i can't find how to change it. I have found only function remapColumns which don't work how I want

Comment: I fund a way to do it with function remapColumns e.g. $('#list').remapColumns([1,3,2,0], true, false]); But should be careful when you have extra columns e.g. rownumbers: true or subgrid expand column. This columns can be also reordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way to use [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) in the form

```js
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "Id"}
```

In the case the data which represent rows should be objects having named properties:

```js
{
    "page": 1,
    "total": 37,
    "records": 722,
    "rows": [
        {"Id":1, "Name":"Sample name 1", "Street":"Sample Street 2", "City":"Sample City 3"},
        {"Id":2, "Name":"Sample name 2", "Street":"Sample Street 2", "City":"Sample City 3"}
    ]
}
```

The main disadvantage of the format is increasing of the size of transferred data. Nevertheless it will be the most simple way to solve your problem.

Another way will be usage of `repeatitems: false` in combination with `jsonmap`. It allows to specify how the data for every column will be read from the row of data. One can use dotted names for `jsonmap`:

```js
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: 'Marcin.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Name', 'Street', 'City', 'Id'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', width: 120, jsonmap: "cell.1" },
        { name: 'Street', width: 190, jsonmap: "cell.2" },
        { name: 'City', width: 90, jsonmap: "cell.3" },
        { name: 'Id', width: 55, align: 'center', jsonmap: "cell.0" }
    ],
    height: "auto",
    gridview: true,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "Id" }
});
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Marcin.htm) looks as

[image]

In more complex cases one can use `jsonmap` as function which read the item for the column from the object which represent the row. For example one can rewrite definition of the column `'Id'` to the following

```js
{ name: 'Id', width: 55, align: 'center',
    jsonmap: function (obj) { // "cell.0"
        return obj.cell[0];
    }}
```

[The modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Marcin_.htm) display the same results.